# How to create a draggable panel on iphone like the notifications panel

Tags: iphone, notifications, panel, draggable, swipe

i'm trying to create a draggable panel/view (on iphone) that you can open bottom to top something like the notifications panel of ios5, i think is a mix between sweep and draggable but i dont know.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with down direction, and check that it starts close enough to the top, then animate a view from above the visible area to the visible area.

Or if you want to be able to drag it from the top you could use a UIPanGestureRecognizer, again checking that it starts close enough to the top. Get the panning translation using

```
- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view
```

then translate the view by the same amount.